# Problem with msvld: unable to load firmware data and msvld: init failed, -19 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, icons, .desktop

i have a problem with my ubuntu 20.04 lts i work in virtualbox and i accidentally dragged the app icon to other place in dock and the icon the icon froze in place in dock.

My desktop don't work i can't click in settings and app icon only opening running applications worked i type in terminal dmesg and i see:

**Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvc1_fuc084 failed with error -2**

**msvld: unable to load firmware data**

**msvld: init failed, -19**

i think this is a problem with graphic drivers i had gt750

After restart ubuntu everything is good i can click at the apps settings..
but this still shows up:

**Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvc1_fuc084 failed with error -2**

**msvld: unable to load firmware data**

**msvld: init failed, -19**

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found a problem of frozen desktop. I have only 2gb of swap file, i was running 2-3 virtualbox machines and this used a lot of memory

**High RAM usage can freeze the desktop in ubuntu if you don't have enough swap memory**

Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvc1_fuc084 failed with error -2

msvld: unable to load firmware data

msvld: init failed, -19

This was a graphic card drivers error because i have old drivers